# String.Replace for Path and Url

Tags: string, url, replace, path, filepath

I have a problem about path string data. I have a string columb in Database and keep path in this columb.Like this;

```
D:\SCANNEDDOCUMENTS\2\3C9DED0628F44190ABF92D3C14F14A14-2-D.pdf
```

In my project i'll reach documents on IIS.I config all settings for IIS. And I need an Url like this;

```
HTTP://LOCALHOST/SCANNEDDOCUMENTS/2/3C9DED0628F44190ABF92D3C14F14A14-2-D.pdf
```

And i don't want to change paths in database.They're original local path.Only i need change on viewmodel. So need replace first path to second Url. And when i get path value from database i saw that:

```
D:\\SCANNEDDOCUMENTS\\2\\3C9DED0628F44190ABF92D3C14F14A14-2-D.pdf
```

There is double backslash? Why? And how can replace this like my wanted Url?

I tried several thing like;

```
private static string ReplaceDocumentPathLocalToWeb(string path)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
        {
            SArchiveModule archivingModule = ContainerManager.Container.GetInstance<SArchiveModule>();
            SbtGeneralParameterModel parameter = archivingModule.GetGeneralParameters();
            string docDirectory = parameter.DocumentDirectoryPath;
            string docWebDirectory = parameter.DocumentWebRootPath + @"/" + parameter.DocumentWebFolderPath;
            path.Replace(docDirectory, docWebDirectory);
            path.Replace("\"", "/");
            if (path.StartsWith(@"/"))
            {
                path.TrimStart(new char[] { '/' });
            }
            if (path.EndsWith(@"/"))
            {
                path.TrimEnd(new char[] { '/' });
            }
        }
        return path;
    }
```

path="D:\SCANNEDDOCUMENTS\2\3C9DED0628F44190ABF92D3C14F14A14-2-D.pdf";

parameters from database too;

docDirectory="D:\SCANNEDDOCUMENTS"
docWebDirectory="HTTP://LOCALHOST/SCANNEDDOCUMENTS"

But this code is not working too:

```
   path.Replace(docDirectory, docWebDirectory);
```

What should i do for replace? And why my data came with double backslash? In database it's with one backslash?

Answer (score 0):

So sorry my wrong. Now i got the problem. I couldn't see the string.replace result 'cause i need use code like:

```
path=path.Replace(docDirectory, docWebDirectory);
        path=path.Replace("\"", "/");
        if (path.StartsWith(@"/"))
        {
            path=path.TrimStart(new char[] { '/' });
        }
        if (path.EndsWith(@"/"))
        {
            path=enter code here`path.TrimEnd(new char[] { '/' });
        }
```

It's really silly mistake...